# Transform a country feature collection (polygon) to a single polygon outlining the entire country to avoid user memory exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Is there an efficient way to obtain the outline of a country (e.g., Australia) based on feature collection instead of drawing with the geometry tool?

Input:

```
var AUS_comp = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2013").filterMetadata("cc","equals","AS")
```

Output:

[image]

P/S: My initial objectives was to plot a graph via `ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear` of a dataset (FIRMS hotspots) across the country. However, filtering with the `AUS_comp` feature collections seems to be consuming too much resources and resulting in user memory exceeded / computation timeout. I am not sure whether converting the feature collections to a single polygon would be the best solution for this issue.

Full
code (JavaScript) Google Earth Engine:

```
var AUS = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[127.3689462855952, -13.491075137327103],[123.8533212855952, -16.29372317317216],[121.5681650355952, -17.638732215007032], [120.4255869105952, -19.637359606938393],
          [116.1189462855952, -20.627589346224404],[113.3943369105952, -23.316982594400656],[113.6580087855952, -25.55725738666083],[114.8884775355952, -30.216305297255722],
          [114.6248056605952, -33.64658749466065],[116.7341806605952, -34.95344585475264],[120.0740244105952, -34.66479312507612],[122.8865244105952, -34.30255856657303],
          [126.2263681605952, -32.69019447983865],[130.4451181605952, -31.798174980040457],[133.5212900355952, -32.542133943536214],[135.2791025355952, -35.169270873633344],
          [137.6521494105952, -34.22992311043601],[139.4978525355952, -37.43556659275122],[145.5623056605952, -39.02340657205664],[149.5173837855952, -38.061021987992696],
          [152.1541025355952, -34.66479312507612],[153.2087900355952, -25.319148988654078],[146.6169931605952, -18.640985563798928],[142.2224619105952, -11.086718680136846],
          [141.3435556605952, -15.617690983472107],[140.1130869105952, -17.387282126561526],[136.0701181605952, -14.769515119489446],[137.0369150355952, -12.033891737255088],
          [132.2908212855952, -11.259168237228634],[129.2146494105952, -14.088573349609213]]]);
var AUS_comp = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2013").filterMetadata("cc","equals","AS")

Map.addLayer(AUS_comp,{},'self drawn australlia')
Map.addLayer(AUS,{color: 'red'},'aus from feature collection')
Map.centerObject(AUS_comp,5);

// Filter based on single drawn polygon (AUS) - no issue
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').select('T21').filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-03-31');
var series = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear(dataset, 'T21', AUS, ee.Reducer.count())
                                                    .setOptions({
                                                      title: 'Number of fires in Australia',
                                                       vAxis: {title: 'Number of Fires'},
                                                       hAxis: {title: 'Day of Year'}});
print(series); 


//Filter bound based on the feature collection - too many multipolgon - user memory exceeded / computation timeout
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').select('T21').filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-03-31');
var series1 = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear(dataset, 'T21', AUS_comp, ee.Reducer.count())
                                                    .setOptions({
                                                      title: 'Number of fires in Australia',
                                                       vAxis: {title: 'Number of Fires'},
                                                       hAxis: {title: 'Day of Year'}});
print(series1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the `chart.image()` functionality prefer to have inputs of type `geometry()` as opposed to `ee.Feature()`. This might solve your issue partially:

```
var series1 = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear({imageCollection: dataset, 
                                              bandName:'T21', region:largest.geometry(), 
                                              regionReducer:ee.Reducer.count(),
                                              scale:1000})
                                                    .setOptions({
                                                      title: 'Number of fires in Australia',
                                                       vAxis: {title: 'Number of Fires'},
                                                       hAxis: {title: 'Day of Year'}});
```

It is still good practice though to reduce the amount of vertices when you don't need them, e.g. by creating a bbox, convex hull or something similar. You can do that for the entire FeatureCollection or create a convex hull and do it for each feature seperately. You can then also add a area estimate to filter on, e.g. select the largest or only land masses above a certain threshold:

```
var Aus_simple = AUS_comp.map(function(x){
  var simpleFeat = x.simplify(1000)
  
  var area = simpleFeat.area() // in m2
  var convex = x.convexHull(1000)
  var areaConvex = convex.area() // in m2

  return(convex.copyProperties(x).set({area:area,
    areaConvex: areaConvex
  }))
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8b4d27e6bab684805121492bab72d49